# How can I get type double array from List<string>?

Tags: c#, linq, list

```
var array1 = (from ir in PMEC.InterestRateSet
              select new List<string> { ir.Tenor.ToString() }).ToList();

var array2 = (from ir in PMEC.InterestRateSet
              select new List<string> { ir.Rate.ToString() }).ToList();

array1.AddRange(array2);

var array = array1.ToArray();
```

For example, `array1` has six numbers, `array2` has six numbers, then after they are combined, `array` has 12 numbers.

Then what should I do in order to get array of type double?

Comment: Why do you name your lists `array`?

Comment: Indeed - do you need an array or a list?

Comment: Thank you all for your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Tenor` and `Rate` are already `double` properties you should not convert them to string.

```
List<double> tenorList = PMEC.InterestRateSet
    .Select(irs => irs.Tenor) 
    .ToList();
List<double> rateList = PMEC.InterestRateSet
    .Select(irs => irs.Rate) 
    .ToList();
List<double> tenorRateList = tenorList.Concat(rateList).ToList();
// or...
tenorList.AddRange(rateList); // modifies first list
```

But that seems to be pointless, you would get 12 doubles in your sample even if you have only 6 objects in `InterestRateSet`. Much better would be to select both properties at once:

```
var tenorRateList = PMEC.InterestRateSet
    .Select(irs => new { Tenor = irs.Tenor, Rate =irs.Rate} ) 
    .ToList(); // list of anonymous type
```

---

In general, if you have a string and you want to convert it to double use `double.Parse` or `double.TryParse`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you very much for your reply. I am a beginner. If I select them at once, how to change tenorRateList of type anonymous to array of type double (i.e., six number of type double in the first column and six in the second column)? Thank you. @Tim Schmelter

Comment: Hi Tim, if I use your code above, it says "cannot convert type List<double?> to List<double>". The property is nullable. How to fix it now? Thank you.

Comment: You have to select the Value property of the nullable to get the double. But what value do you want to take if its null? If you want to treat nulls as zero: .Select(irs => irs.Rate ?? 0)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to parse the list of strings in to a list of doubles ...

```
var result = array1.Select(i => double.Parse(i)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Darth, thank you for your reply! I tried your way, but some error with code "double.Parse(i)". It says "The best overloaded method match for 'double.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments". How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Darth, maybe because they are nullable? How to fix it? I don't want to change my entity property now and generate database again.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<double> ListOfDouble =(from str in ListOfString let d=double.Parse(str) select d).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
var result = array1.Select(i => i==null?0;double.Parse(i)).ToList();
```